# Ant build script not running for java servlet class

Tags: java, ant, jboss

Iam trying to run my Ant build and creating build is successful. i also see the compiled classes in the destination folder being created. But when i take that war file and deploy in the jboss server ,it gives me exception saying classnotfound exception of my class.

Build.xml looks like :

```
      <property name="javabase" value="${gi.basedir}/search/src"/>
  <property name="targetdir" value="${gi.basedir}/search/targets"/>
  <property name="wardir" value="${targetdir}/war"/>
  <property name="externaljars" value="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib"/>
  <property name="java-compiled" value="${targetdir}/java-compiled"/>
  <property name="srchwardir" value="${wardir}/warpath"/>

  <target name="init" depends="clean">
         <mkdir dir="${srchwardir}"/>
     <mkdir dir="${targetdir}"/>
     <mkdir dir="${wardir}"/>
  </target>

 <target name="compile" depends="init" description="compile the source " >
    <mkdir dir="${java-compiled}"/>
    <!-- Compile the java code from ${src} into ${java-compiled} -->
    <javac srcdir="${javabase}" destdir="${java-compiled}">
<include name="agsrchpackage.*.java"/>

    </javac>
     </target>

<target name="Main" depends="compile">
    <description>Main target</description>
 </target>

<path id="java.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${externaljars}">
        <include name="*.jar" />
    </fileset>
    </path>
<war destfile="${srchwardir}/agsrchpackage.war" webxml="WebContent/WEBINF/web.xml">
    </war>  

</project>
```

Comment: This sounds like a couple problems.  1) What's the build file look like and where is it supposed to write the compiled classes  2) The war is not very useful without some .class files in it  3) Please try to format your input text a bit better - see the helps for - but generally line starts with 4 leading spaces helps a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were a couple problems in the build script - here's one I got running, using your folder names.  You didn't have a clean target and the webxml parameter was wrong - should be "WEB-INF" for the folder not just WEBINF.

This will build a war.  It also looks like you were not including your class in the war being build.  I added the    tag within the war tag.

```
 <project name="test" basedir="." default="usage">

 <property name="gi.basedir" value="."/>
 <property name="javabase" value="${gi.basedir}/search/src"/>
 <property name="targetdir" value="${gi.basedir}/search/targets"/>
 <property name="wardir" value="${targetdir}/war"/>
 <property name="externaljars" value="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib"/>
 <property name="java-compiled" value="${targetdir}/java-compiled"/>
 <property name="srchwardir" value="${wardir}/warpath"/>

 <path id="java.classpath">
   <fileset dir="${externaljars}">
     <include name="*.jar" />
   </fileset>
 </path>

 <target name="clean">
    <delete dir="${srchwardir}"/>
    <delete dir="${targetdir}"/>
    <delete dir="${wardir}"/>
 </target>

 <target name="init" depends="clean">
    <mkdir dir="${srchwardir}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${targetdir}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${wardir}"/>
 </target>

<target name="compile" depends="init" description="compile the source " >
   <mkdir dir="${java-compiled}"/>
   <javac srcdir="${javabase}" destdir="${java-compiled}">
     <classpath refid="java.classpath"/>
   </javac>
</target>

<target name="war" depends="compile">
   <war destfile="${srchwardir}/agsrchpackage.war" webxml="WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml">
       <classes dir="${java-compiled}"/>
       <lib dir="${externaljars}">
       <include name="**/*.jar"/>
       </lib>
       <fileset dir="${javabase}">
           <include name="**/log4j.properties"/>
      </fileset>
   </war>  
 </target>

</project>
```

You can view the contents of the war by running the jar program like so and will list out the content of the war.

```
jar -tf search/targets/war/warpath/arsrchpackage.war
```

Comment: where we are creating a war file in the above code? i see clean,init and compile . So i need to include war also right?

Comment: i added for war as                                                  <war destfile="${taagIndexwardir}/taagupdateindex.war"  webxml="WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml">                            <lib dir="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib"/>
<classes dir="${javabase}"/>   
</war>

Comment: Youcan make the war target 'dependsOn' the compile target, or you can create an 'all' target to like follows  <target name="all" dependsOn="clean,init,compile,war"/> - haven't syntax checked this - but that is the idea - all in one - then you can change the "dfault" value at the top to all, then you just run -> "ant" - assuming your build file is named build.xml

Comment: But does the war needs to include all java classes and lib? what is syntax to write the war with including the classes. i can see the contents of war file as Web-Inf/classes/arsrchpackage/Index.java...but it doesnt include the compiled classes. Also the build is successful and when i run the war in jboss server,it says the classnot found exception for this Index.java class.

Comment: Doh - sorry - looks like part of my final result got chopped off and unfortunately it is at home on my personal machine. The war target/task was NOT including the classes so I added that to the war target/task.   I can try to recreate some of that now or edit my post tonight after I get home?

Comment: Strange because when I edit my response, my war target is in the response.  I will post 'another' answer with just that target.

Comment: Okay - I have reformatted my response and now the war target is showing - sorry about that. The gist is that the war target not only includes the web.xml, but the classes tag points to the compiled code to include and the lib tag is used to pickup the other jars to be included.  Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks a lot .It looks like it is working now. One more query is that it is not including the log4j.properties file which is under src directory {javabase} . How can i include that in war file too? So i can see the logs getting generated from my class.

Comment: Check the response - I added the <fileset> that should cover it - not tested but idea is point fileset to folder and file inside the war task and those files also get include.

Comment: Thanks and i have included the line. It looks like the build is successful and war gets created . Even iam able to deploy that war with no errors. But i dont see the logger getting created based on path i mentioned in log4j.properties file.Any suggestions?

Comment: Checkout some log4j doc, like the following link:  https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html

Comment: hey thanks...But log4j is configured and it works with no issues. I was able to see the logs getting generated before i build this war using ant. once i run the ant script ,i dont find the logproperties.class files in the compiled location {java-compiled}. May be that is the reason?

Comment: Log4J uses the log4j.properties file for configuration and there should not be a logproperties.class.  The log4j.properties file should be in in the root folder of the war so that your code that calls log4j can find it.

Comment: yeah..Now i get the log4.properties file in the war file by including all the jars in the classpath. Now even though i get log4j.proeries in my war file. i still dont see the logs getting generated. This is only happening when i build the war using ant script. If i build the war direclty from eclipse ,i dont find this issue and the logs get created. Shall i create a different post for this issue?

Comment: Yes, this diaglog has gone on enough.  Start with a clean post/question.